# Gremlin GraphTraversalSource retrieve vertex properties with cardinality

Tags: janusgraph, gremlin-server

I have added a vertex with a property having Cartinality.set.

Is it possible to retrieve vertex properties and also the type (or Cardinality) of the property values ?

For example using `graphTraversalSource.V(id).valueMap(true).next();` is there a way of identifying if a map value is a list or a set ?

Answer (score 1):

There are no Gremlin steps to test if a list is really a list or a set. The cardinality types are essentially applied when you add to the multi property (list or set). However, if you are using JanusGraph, you can explicitly define that the schema for a property key is SINGLE, SET, or LIST. There is more information here https://docs.janusgraph.org/basics/schema/